# Character set not being applied correctly

Tags: java

I have a Spark Java web service that receives requests in UTF-8. When extended characters like umlauts or letters with tildes are received, they don't correctly contain the correct character when converted to a string.  To debug:

1) I receive the request and display its bytes as Hex values (this contains the correct characters).

2) I then convert the received bytes to a string (specifying the charset of UTF-8).

3) Finally, I again display the string from step 2 as Hex values.

Unfortunately, the hex values from step 1 don't match the hex values from step 3.  Below is the code I'm using:

```
    byte[] bytes = request.bodyAsBytes();


    LOGGER.debug( "1 - Body as bytes: " );
    LOGGER.debug( javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes) );
    LOGGER.debug( "1 - End of body" );

    //  charset hard coded to UTF-8 for testing...
    String charSet = requestHeadersDto.getCharacterSet().equals( "" ) ? DEFAULT_CHAR_SET : requestHeadersDto.getCharacterSet();
    LOGGER.debug( "Charset: " + charSet );
    String xml = new String( bytes , charSet );


    LOGGER.debug( "2 - Body as bytes: " );
    LOGGER.debug( javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( xml.getBytes() ) );
    LOGGER.debug( "2 - End of body" );
```

What am I doing wrong?  TIA.

Comment: You're asking for bytes out of the String *again*, after you already converted the bytes to String and obtained a correct String out of it. That's wrong. You have a String. Forget about bytes.

Comment: and `getBytes` is using which Charset, that is, what is the platform default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml.getBytes()
```

Should be:

```
xml.getBytes(charSet)
```

or

```
xml.getBytes(Charset.forName(charSet))
```

Comment: Would you satisfy my curiosity and explain why the Charset.forName() version is preferable?

Comment: You are right, apparently, it's the same thing. Let me change my answer then.